# What does the green arrow in Unitys MonoDevelop mean?

Tags: unity, monodevelop

What does the green arrow in Unitys MonoDevelop mean? It comes up while I am debugging my code:

[image]

Comment: Isn't that the line the debugger is currently executing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The green arrow in MonoDevelop shows the line in your code the game is currently executing. You can read more about this, and debugging using MonoDevelop in general [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/monodevelops-debugger).